# Laravel uploading multiple images with error idback: "The idback must be a file of type: jpg, jpeg, png."

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, inertiajs

I'm using Laravel 8 and Vue.js to making an form where I uploading two images (every each one into different paths and by different input fields).

I was surfing on internet and find out nothing what will be described my situation.

The Error I got in the Google Chrome Dev Tools -> Network -> Preview:

```
idback: "The idback must be a file of type: jpg, jpeg, png."
idfront: "The idfront must be a file of type: jpg, jpeg, png."
```

But the file which I post into form was .jpg

My VerificationController.php store function:

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{
    $request->validate([
      'firstname' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
      'lastname' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
      'idfront' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:2048',
      'idback' => 'required||mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:2048',
    ]);
    
    
    
    
    if($request->hasFile('idfront') && $request->hasFile('idback')) {
       $file_front = time().'.'.$request->file('idfront')->extension();
       $file_back = time().'.'.$request->file('idback')->extension();
       
       $request->file('idfront')->storeAs('user_verifications/front', $file_front);
       $request->file('idback')->storeAs('user_verifications/back', $file_back);
       
       $user = auth()->user();
       $user = DB::table('users')->where('id', $user->id)->first();
       $user->verified = "yes";
       $user->save();
       
          
       $verification = new Verification();
       $verification->user_id = $user->id;
       $verification->firstname = $request->input('firstname');
       $verification->lastname = $request->input('lastname');
       $verification->country = $request->input('country');
       $verification->id_front_path = $file_front;
       $verification->id_back_path = $file_back;
       $verification->save();
          
       DB:commit();

    }



}
```

The Verify.vue file, with axios request:

```
data() {
        return {
            verificationForm: this.$inertia.form({
                firstname: '',
                lastname: '',
                country: 'USA',
                options: [
                  { text: 'United States', value: 'USA' },
                  { text: 'United Kingdom', value: 'UK' },
                  { text: 'Afghanistan', value: 'Afghanistan' },
                  {...},
                ],
                idfront: '',
                idback: '',
            }, {
                bag: 'createVerification',
                resetOnSuccess: false,
            }),
        }
    },
     methods: {
        createVerification() {
            let formData = new FormData();
            
            formData.append('idfront', idfront);
            formData.append('idback', idback);
            
            this.verificationForm.post('/user/verify',
                formData, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                    }
                }
              ).then(function() {
                    console.log(idfront);
                    console.log(idback);
              })
              .catch(function() {
                    console.log(idfront);
                    console.log(idback);
              });
        },
        handleFileUpload() {
            const idfront = this.$refs.idfront.files[0];
            const idback = this.$refs.idback.files[0];
        }
    }
}
```

And the  tag:

```
<form @submit.prevent="$emit('submitted')" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

The Inputs in Verify.vue:

```
<jet-input-file id="idfront" type="file" ref="idfront" name="idfront" placeholder="Front side of ID" v-model="verificationForm.idfront" v-on:change="handleFileUpload()" />
<jet-input-error :message="verificationForm.error('idfront')" />
                            
                            
<jet-input-file id="idback" type="file" ref="idback" name="idback" placeholder="Back side of ID" v-model="verificationForm.idback" v-on:change="handleFileUpload()"/>
<jet-input-error :message="verificationForm.error('idback')" />
```

Now, I saw that this is in the POST request (every other inputs was submitted correctly, but there are not):

```
idback: "C:\fakepath\6171500.jpg"
idfront: "C:\fakepath\32_d.jpg"
```

After edit: It will still gives me `C:/fakepath/image.jpg` and `C:/fakepath/image2.jpg` in my request (and throws status 302), and in Dev Console will shows me this:

[Input in Dev Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9Lyb.png)

Comment: Are you sure your form is submitted correctly? Check your network tab in the dev pane of your browser and check the contents of your post.

Comment: @MaartenVeerman I found the problem, but I don't know the correctly solution in my code. I also edited the post with this informations.

Answer (score 0):

File uploads are different from standard plain text form uploads, since the file object needs to be sent.

In non-ajax forms this requires the form content-type to be set to `multipart/form-data` and the browser will take care of submitting the file object.

In ajax form submissions, like in your case, you need to set the content-type, and take care of submitting the file object yourself.

In your current situation you are only submitting the file path, a string representation of the file object. You need to get hold of the file object, for example by defining a `ref` on your file input, and accessing the object using:

```js
const fileA = this.$refs.fileA.files[0];
```

All is well described here: https://serversideup.net/uploading-files-vuejs-axios/

I suggest you read through that tutorial. It clearly showed how to define the `FormData` object to be sent to the server.

Comment: Hi, @Maarten Veerman, okay, let me ask you if I understand correctly your row: const fileA = this.$refs.fileA.files[0];     accessing to the first file in list and fileA is value from ref="" in your input?

Comment: I also maked some edit now.. But still not works.. When I trying to catch it will writes me TypeError: Cannot read property 'idfront' of undefined (I trying to console.log(this.idfront) and console.log(this.idback) )

Comment: Where are you trying to perform the console.log? Could you show how you added the `ref`? I think you did it right though, since in your first comment you do understand my answer correctly.

Comment: I just maked update with everything. I using name="" and ref="" (both too).

Comment: The console shows you can access the input element. What happens when you log its `files` property?

Comment: @Marteen Veerman Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: files is not defined

Comment: Strange. Could you try to use `document.getElementById()` instead of `$refs`, as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList  just to see what happens...

Comment: I still have c:\fakepath\xxx.jpg in my request and the document.getElementById in console will writes me the input fields..